# Overriding Android default copy paste option

Tags: android

I am developing a chat application in android.In the chat activity i was trying to copy message from chat message and was trying to paste into the EditText where we enter our message.

Everything was working fine.But when i tried to paste my message which I saved using shared preference the default paste option of phone come to front.if i click that button it will paste a message from some other app that run in my device (for example whatsapp).So all i need is two option

1.Disable default paste option of Edittext on its long click
2.To override copy paste feature of android frame work.

I am using DefaultSharedPreference to copy and paste message.
Please help me with your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ClipboardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html) of android for copy and paste instead of using DefaultSharedPreference.

Follow [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_clipboard.htm) for sample tutorial.